# R shiny load workspace

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am learning Shiny and need some help please.

I need to load a very large data.frame from a saved workspace (RData). Once loaded I need to perform analyses and output these to the UI.

I have placed the following code in server.R but it doesn't load the data and then throws an error:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  load("c:/temp/ws1.RData")  
  output$balance_matrix <- renderTable({
    Transaction_history
  })

})

> Error in func() : object 'Transaction_history' not found
```

First, what am I doing wrong here?

Secondly, is this the best place to load the workspace?

Thirdly, can I load it outside the function at the top or will it not be available in the function then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than saving and trying to load the workspace, I'd recommend saving the file individually like,

`saveRDS(Transaction_history, "C:/temp/ws1.RData")`

and then load it in Shiny like,

`Transaction_history <- readRDS("C:/temp/ws1.RData")`

This method will focus on this file by itself. From the `?load` documentation,

> load() replaces all existing objects with the same names in the
>   current environment (typically your workspace, .GlobalEnv) and hence
>   potentially overwrites important data.

Comment: Hallelujah! there's a few hours well spent finding 10,000 ways how not to do it. Thank you